# Criando um programa de Cadastro com Pandas e Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estou criando um controle de despesas para ser usado como um estudo de ciência de dados.
Esta é minha expressão:

```
def cadastro():
    
    descritivo = []
    valor = []
    condicao = []
    
    mes = input('Qual o mês vigente: ')[0:3].upper()
    quantidade = int(input('Quantas compras deseja registrar? '))
    

    for i in range(quantidade):
        dia = input("Qual o dia da sua compra: ")
        des = input('O que você comprou? ').upper()
        val = float(input('Qual o valor da compra: '))
        cond = input('Qual o método de pagamento? ').upper()
        descritivo.append(des)
        valor.append(val)
        condicao.append(cond)
        data = (f'2021/{mes}/{dia}')
        
  
        
        base = { 'Data': data,
                "Descritivo": descritivo,
                "Valor": valor,
                "Condição": condicao}
        
        dados = pd.DataFrame(data=base)
        
        
           
    return dados

cadastro()
```

Do jeito que esta, a data vai ser sempre única para todos os outros valores. Gostaria de saber como faço para acrescentar uma nova data, neste formato 2021/Fev/01 e a partir da data, cadastrar quantos produtos eu quiser.

como peço ao usuário para preencher isso com entrada?

Comment: Não coloque cumprimentos ou agradecimentos em perguntas ou respostas: Ref:https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 0):

Olá, se fizeres append na data como fizeste com os outros dados, vai funcionar como esperavas:

```
descritivo = []
valor = []
condicao = []

data = []
```

e depois:

```
descritivo.append(des)
valor.append(val)
condicao.append(cond)

data.append(f'2021/{mes}/{dia}')
```